# Utilizing asyncio generators and asyncio.as_completed

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I have some code that I am using to **scrape** a url, parse the information, and then drop it into a DB using SQLAlchemy. I'm trying to do it asynchronously while limiting the maximum number of simultaneous requests.

Here is my code:

```
async def get_url(aiohttp_session, url1, url2):
    async with session.get(url1) as r_url1:
       if r_url1.status == 200:
          async with session.get(url2) as r_url2:
             if r_url2.status == 200:
                return await r_url1.json(), await r_url2.json()

async def url_generator(formatted_start_date, formatted_end_date, machine_id, interval):
    interval_start = formatted_start_date
    interval_end = formatted_start_date + interval

    while interval_end <= formatted_end_date:
        yield (f"https://example.org/start={interval_start}"
               f"Start={datetime.strftime(interval_start, DATETIME_FORMAT)}"
               f"&End={datetime.strftime(interval_end, DATETIME_FORMAT)}"
               f"&machines={machine_id}",
               f"https://example.org/start={interval_start}"
               f"Start={datetime.strftime(interval_start, DATETIME_FORMAT)}"
               f"&End={datetime.strftime(interval_end, DATETIME_FORMAT)}"
               f"&machines={machine_id}&groupby=Job"
               )
        interval_start += interval
        interval_end += interval

async def parse(database, url1_json, url2_json):
    """ Do some parsing and save it using credentials stored in the database object """


def main(database, formatted_start_date, formatted_end_date, machine_id, interval):
    async for url1_json, url2_json in asyncio.as_completed(url_generator(formatted_start_date, formatted_end_date, machine_id, interval)):
         parse(database, url1_json, url2_json)
```

I am getting the error `yield from should be used as context manager expression`.

I've tried looking at the [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) as well as the Synchronization Primitives and am still confused as to where I've gone wrong and how I should go about creating tasks from my generator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with the posted code:

- You're trying to use `as_completed` as an async iterator, iterating over its results with `async for`. However, `as_completed` doesn't return an async iterator (at least [not yet](https://bugs.python.org/issue33533)) and must be iterated with regular `for`, and await each yielded object explicitly, as [shown in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed).
- You are passing an async iterator to `as_completed`, whereas it accepts an ordinary container, or (regular) iterable.
- You are using `async for` in a function not defined with `async def`, which should be a syntax error. Also, `parse()` is defined as a coroutine, and you are not awaiting it.

The good news is that, since `url_generator` is already a generator, you don't need `as_completed` at all, you should be able to just iterate over it:

```
async def main(database, formatted_start_date, formatted_end_date,
               machine_id, interval):
    async for url1_json, url2_json in url_generator(
            formatted_start_date, formatted_end_date,
            machine_id, interval)):
        await parse(database, url1_json, url2_json)
```

Note, however, that `async for` won't automatically parallelize the iteration, it will just allow other coroutines to run in parallel with the coroutine that iterates. To parallelize the iteration, you need to call [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) to submit the tasks in parallel, and use an [`asyncio.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore) to limit the number of parallel tasks. For example:

```
async def parse(database, url1_json, url2_json, limit):
    # async with applied to a semaphore ensures that no more than N
    # coroutines that use the same semaphore enter the "with" block
    # in parallel
    async with limit:
        ... code goes here ...

async def main(database, formatted_start_date, formatted_end_date,
               machine_id, interval):
    limit = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

    # create all coroutines in advance using create_task
    # and run them in parallel, relying on the semaphore
    # limit the number of simultaneous requests
    tasks = []
    async for url1_json, url2_json in url_generator(
            formatted_start_date, formatted_end_date,
            machine_id, interval)):
        # this create_task just creates the task - it will
        # start running when we return to the event loop
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(parse(database, url1_json, url2_json, limit))

    # suspend to the event loop, resuming this coroutine only after
    # all the tasks have finished (or any of them raises)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Note that `url_generator` doesn't need to be async because it doesn't need to `await` anything. You can define it with `def` and iterate over it with `for`.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer. Part of my reasoning for making the `url_generator` a generator is that I didn't want to hold all the tasks in memory at the same time. The list of tasks could be in the millions. Does your approach at the bottom only call `next()` when the Semaphore has `release()` called or does it hold all the tasks in memory at the same time?

Comment: @TMarks The code in the answer holds all tasks in memory at the same time, although most of them will be empty because they'll be stuck waiting on the semaphore. Still, if you are dealing with millions of items, you probably want to avoid creating millions of tasks in advance, and have them "fight" over the semaphore. (The fighting should still be algorithmically efficient, but you will be wasting memory.)

Comment: @TMarks You can create a bounded queue, create a fixed number of coroutines (as many of them as high you want the simultaneous access limit to be) to drain the queue/contact the database, and fill the queue from `main()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51816763/1600898) for an example.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342, I appreciate all the effort you put into your answers. I'll go check out that link you posted and try and implement a solution like that.