# python asyncio parallel processing with a dynamic tasks queue

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, threadpool, aiohttp

I'm new to `asyncio`. Most `asyncio` code examples show parallel processing with a fixed number of tasks:

```py
tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(download_one(url)) for url in urls]
await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

I need to download a large number of URLs. I'm currently using `aiohttp + asyncio` in the aforementioned way to run download the files in batches of let's say 16 concurrent tasks.

The problem with this approach is that the `asyncio` operation blocks *(no puns intended)* until the entire batch has been completed.

How can I dynamically add a new task to the queue as soon as a task is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my initial solution (using consumer-producer design pattern):

```py
import asyncio, random

urls = ['url1',....]

def get_url() -> str | None:
    global urls
    return urls.pop() if any(urls) else None


async def producer(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        if queue.full():
            print(f"queue full ({queue.qsize()}), sleeping...")
            await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
            continue

        # get a url to fetch
        url = get_url()
        if not url:
            break
        print(f"PRODUCED: {url}")
        await queue.put(url)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


async def consumer(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        url = await queue.get()
        # simulate I/O operation
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
        queue.task_done()
        print(f"CONSUMED: {url}")


async def main():
    concurrency = 3
    queue: asyncio.Queue = asyncio.Queue(concurrency)

    # fire up the both producers and consumers
    consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue)) for _ in range(concurrency)]
    producers = [asyncio.create_task(producer(queue)) for _ in range(1)]

    # with both producers and consumers running, wait for
    # the producers to finish
    await asyncio.gather(*producers)
    print("---- done producing")

    # wait for the remaining tasks to be processed
    await queue.join()

    # cancel the consumers, which are now idle
    for c in consumers:
        c.cancel()


asyncio.run(main())
```

In my case, since the list of urls to process is pretty huge (in double digit millions), the producer waits for workers to become available before pushing another task in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiprocessing` and put all your concurrent tasks into a loop. then check the current active processes by `len(multiprocessing.active_children())`.

Firstly, declare a max concurrent tasks you want to process:

```
max_processes = 4
```

Define the all tasks you wanna handle:

```
numberOfTasks = 16
```

Suppose, you will perform that task using `printing()` function:

```
def printing(start, end):
  print(f'\n{start} - {end}\n')
```

Then loop:

```
for i in range(numberOfTasks + 1):
  if(len(multiprocessing.active_children()) < max_processes):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 1)
    pool.apply_async(printing, args=(0, 100))

  else:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

With each loop, the program will create a pool with 1 process, the number of processes is equal to `max_processes`, the program will wait until the pool is done and then open a new task next.

Comment: Is that really related to the question? Also, the _loop_ part is an extremely convoluted way of doing `with multiprocessing.Pool(max_processes) as pool: pool.starmap(printing, [(0, 100)] * number_of_tasks)`.